ewma from SAS to Python with reset
I'm trying to translate the SAS code for an EWMA control chart into Python. It is a control chart with predefined UCL and LCL, based on historically determined values.
In SAS, I introduced the RESET option, which allows the chart value to return within the control limits after exceeding them.
This is the SAS statement:
proc macontrol data=per_carta_ewma limits=boc._04_limiti;
ewmachart residui*ISO_date /reset weight=&lambda_ewma nochart
outtable=EWMA;
run;

I prepared this piece of Python code, but I couldn't find a reset option:
UCL = 3 * np.sqrt((1 - lambda_ewma) / lambda_ewma) * ewma_ante.std()
LCL = -3 * np.sqrt((1 - lambda_ewma) / lambda_ewma) * ewma_ante.std()
<other code>
ewma = pd.Series(per_carta_ewma['residui']).ewm(alpha=lambda_ewma).mean()
per_carta_ewma['EWMA'] = ewma
per_carta_ewma['alert'] = np.where(per_carta_ewma['EWMA'] > UCL, 'UPPER', 
 np.where(per_carta_ewma['EWMA'] < LCL, 'LOWER', ''))
                               

Does anyone know how to introduce a reset in this control chart?
Thanks in advance!
